# Why are the edge items in Grid truncated?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, options, grid-layouts

The first and last rows and columns of my `Grid`s always seem to be smaller than all the other rows in my `Grid`, as of they had been truncated.

For example

```
Grid[Array[#1 + #2 &, {5, 5}],ItemSize -> {2, 2},BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
       Background -> {
          {Green, Automatic, LightRed, Automatic, Green}, 
          {LightBlue, Automatic, Yellow, Automatic, LightBlue}}]
```

gives

[image]

in which all of the elements in the first and last rows are noticeably shorter, and all the elements in the first and last column are noticeably narrower, than all other elements.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: There are no spacings outside so `Spacings -> {0, 0}` should work. But I agree it's not what one would expect.

Comment: @Kuba: Wow, not at all what one would expect.

Comment: @Kuba Please define "one"

Comment: @belisarius: We two, for a start.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius So `one == two`. You're working modulo zero.

Comment: @belisarius: Not quite `"one" ≥ 2`, or more to the point `"one" ≥ 66.7%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no spacings outside so `Spacings -> {0, 0}` should work. [...]